# When to use 'know' and 'knows'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Do you use 'know' or 'knows' in this sentence

> As the clued-up population of this century know/knows...

My English tutor suggests 'knows'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"population" is the subject here, and its singular, so it should be:

> As the clued-up population of this century *knows*...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, especially in British English, to use a plural verb after a subject which is a collective noun - company, team, group, staff, and, among others, population.

> the British population do not go in for revolution
>
> the British population do not find it as enticing as we do back home
>
> the British population do not blame green levies for the crisis
>
> the British population do not often cook food from raw ingredients

If writing for an American audience, it would be best to stick to singular verbs. Your tutor may be aware of this.

Comment: So I can use know if writing for an American population?